# Как рисовать в WPF без сглаживания?

Tags: wpf

Возникла необходимость нарисовать поверхность на основе примитивов (лаба по компьютерной графике). Поверхность рисуется в собственном контроле через переопределение OnRender (DrawingContext и т.д.).
Однако, обнаружился вот такой вот дефект ("прозрачные" полосы между полигонами, конкретно здесь они белые):

[image: собственно сама поверхность]

Треугольники рисую через PolyLineSegment. Все полигоны использует общий массив точек, и смежные стороны лежат на одних и тех же точках. Так что проблема не в неверных координатах.

Вот тот же дефект на DrawRectangle для сомневающихся.

[image: матрица Адамара]

Предполагаю что проблема в сглаживании. В пограничный пиксель устанавливается цвет занимающий промежуточное значение между фоном и полигоном. Т.к. закрашивание происходит не одновременно, то в качестве фона выступает результат предыдущего покраса.

Упрощенно, если считать что цвета соседних полигонов Red и Blue, которые накрывают пиксель на 0.6 и 0.4 соответственно, то его цвет будет не 0.6*Red + 0.4*Blue, а 0.36*Red + 0.24*Background + 0.4*Blue.

Не знаю есть ли кошерный способ избавится от этого, но очевидно, что при рисовании без сглаживания данного глюка не будет (пиксель будет принадлежать одному/последнему полигону). Вопрос: как отключить сглаживание при рисовании?

// вариант с установкой Stroke не предлагать,  в рамках лабы он неприемлем по "идейным" соображениям

Comment: Не могли бы вы обосновать ваше «очевидно»?

Comment: Развернул, надеюсь донес мысль.

Comment: А может, вы дадите минимальный код, воспроизводящий проблему? Скажем, с двумя треугольниками.

Comment: Кстати, попробуйте `RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"` на ваш `Path`.

Comment: ... или на тот элемент, в котором вы рисуете. Если у вас он не в XAML, это пишется как `element.SetValue(RenderOptions.EdgeModeProperty, EdgeMode.Aliased);` или `RenderOptions.SetEdgeMode(element, EdgeMode.Aliased);`

Comment: Помогло! Правда менять пришлось не у Path, а у DrawingGroup, в котором все эти полигоны лежали. После пар разверну решение. // @VladD Если оформите комментарий как ответ, я отмечу как решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По результатам обсуждения в комментариях:

Antialiasing можно отключить при помощи

```
RenderOptions.SetEdgeMode(element, EdgeMode.Aliased);
```

на отцовском элементе. В нашем случае, это элемент `DrawingGroup`, содержащий полигоны.