# Цвет Line светлее заданного когда StrokeThickness 1

Tags: c#, wpf

```
<Border>
  <Line Fill="Black" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" X1="0" Y1="0" X2="10" Y2="0" Opacity="1" />
</Border>
```

Цвет не черный, а серый:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему?

Когда StrokeThickness > 1 то все нормально

Comment: Пробовали [сглаживание отключить](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/463050/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-wpf-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)?

Comment: @tym32167 нет, не знал, помогло, спасибо

Comment: на здоровье :).